# Angular Chart JS does not render if EnableOptimizations is enabled MVC

Tags: .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm working in an application that uses [Angular-Chart-Js](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js) I've added the scripts in my BundleConfig.cs, if the EnableOptimization is set as false, the chart shows correctly, but when I switch the value to false, the chart is not rendered and no JavaScript exception it's shown in the Dev Tools Console.

## Bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
            "~/Scripts/angular.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-local-storage.js"               
           ));


        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/chart").Include(
            "~/Scripts/Chart.js",
            "~/Scripts/angular-chart.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app").Include(
             "~/app/app.js",
             "~/app-config.js"               
             ));          

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/semantic").Include(
                "~/Scripts/semantic.js"
            ));


        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
            .Include("~/Content/semantic.css",                     
                  "~/Content/angular-chart.css",
                  "~/Content/kendo/kendo.se.css",
                  "~/Content/App/main.css",
                  "~/Content/App/login.css"));
```

Even if I add the .js files directly in the _Layout.cshtml doesn't work if the Optimization is true.

Has anyone faced this issue?

#### UPDATE

I've tested pulling out from the bundle config my app.js file, then it worked. It seems when the app.js gets minified it does not take the injection.

#### app.js

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('TheApp', ['chart.js']);

app.config(['ChartJsProvider', function (ChartJsProvider) {
    // Configure defaults
}]);
```

And this is the controller

#### chartController.js

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('TheApp');

app.controller('ChartController', ['$scope', 'ChartService', function ($scope, chartService) {
 //Some stuff working here
}]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Open up your browser console and see whether you have any js errors.

Comment: @Shyju no errors are shown